# Ignore a column while learning, but keep it for later reference in SKLearn

Tags: scikit-learn, attributes

Is there a way in sklearn to keep a column in the test/train set but ignore it for learning? 
Let's say I have a column called "ID" with a bunch of others. I want to ignore "ID" and use other columns while building a model, but have "ID" in the prediction result. I need to be able to identify which prediction result belongs to which "ID".

Comment: Did you manage to implement this? The links in the answer are all 404s.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) with a step to select the columns for training.

Some examples can be found in scikit-learn documentation:

- Using FunctionTransformer: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py
- Using a custom "ItemSelector" class: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html